# How to make a localPost with media using GMB API?

Tags: google-my-business-api

I am able to make localPost using `GMB` api.

However, when I add media, it gives me an error.

The error is as following.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

My source code is as following.
Also, I installed google/apiclient from github and GMB library from [here](https://developers.google.com/my-business/samples/google-api-services-mybusiness-v4p6-php-rev-20200422-1.zip?hl=ja.)

```
$mediaItem = new \Google_Service_MyBusiness_MediaItem();                                                                                                                                           
$mediaItem->setSourceUrl("https://example.com/test");                                                                                                                                     
$mediaItem->setMediaFormat('PHOTO');                                                                                                                                                               
$media[] = $mediaItem; 
$post = new \Google_Service_MyBusiness_LocalPost(); 
$post->setSummary($summary);
$post->setCallToAction($callToAction);
$post->setMedia($media);
$obj = new \Google_Service_MyBusiness($client); 
$obj->accounts_locations_localPosts->create($accountLocation,$post);
```

If I comment out

```
"$post->setMedia($media);", I can make localPost.
```

Do you have a suggestion for this?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself.

```
Before:
$mediaItem->setSourceUrl("https://example.com/test");                                                                                                                                     

After:
$mediaItem->setSourceUrl("https://example.com/test.jpg");
```

The reason why I could not make localPost is that the image extension should be image extension.
Google API dose not allow us to post the image that has not extension.

Cheers.